# Error Message composer require annotations

Tags: symfony4

[symfony composer hit error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ryUxv.png)

when i am trying to

> composer require annotations

Fix the following mandatory requirements

- Configured default timezone "Asia/Katmandu" must be supported by
   your installation of PHP
- Your default timezone is not supported by PHP. Check for typos in
- your php.ini file and have a look at the list of deprecated
- timezones at http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.others.php.

And i Try to this

> etc/php/php7.3/apache2/php.ini  or etc/php/php7.3/fpm/php.ini

I can edit it

> ;date.timezone = Asia/Katmandu

But not solve

Comment: Edit `etc/php/php7.3/cli/php.ini`.

Comment: `Asia/Katmandu` timezones seems deprecated in PHP so better not use it. Find another timezone name corresponding to your location and try if that works with another timezone.

Comment: Fix typo, Its not Katmandu Its Kathmandu. Asia/Kathmandu.